# How to put a symbol over another in the same line - simultaneous superscript/subscrtipt

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, tipa

Is there a way to put one symbol over the other just as in this shot of a dictionary page?

http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/09/weak.html

Answer (score 3):

A variant of moewe's solution that works independently of the current font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UTF8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % use T1 fonts for proper language support
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}

\makeatletter
% \oalignb is like \oalign, but uses \vbox rather than \vtop
\newcommand{\oalignb}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\baselineskip\z@skip\lineskip.25ex\ialign{##\crcr #1\crcr}}%
}
\newcommand{\textschwasci}{%
  {\check@mathfonts\fontsize\ssf@size\z@\selectfont
   \oalignb{%
     \hidewidth\textsci\hidewidth\cr   % the width should be that of the schwa
     \kern.25ex\textschwa\kern.25ex\cr % some kerning seems appropriate
   }%
 }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textipa{\textprimstress b\textscripta \textlengthmark sk\textschwasci t}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\overset`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  $\overset{\triangle}{\nabla}$ $\overset{\heartsuit}{\spadesuit}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or may be I misunderstood!

Answer (score 2):

This will make the stacked text the height of a lower-cased `t` in the current font size.  If you wish to align the height to a different letter, change the `t` in the `\scalerel` macro argument to something else.  The gap between the stack, prior to scaling, is set to .2ex in the current fontsize, which can be changed also.  `\scalerel` allows an object to be scaled in vertical extent to the size of another object.  `stackengine` package gives convenient stacking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UTF8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % use T1 fonts for proper language support
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\stackedischwa{\scalerel*{\stackon[.2ex]{\textschwa}{\textsci}}{t}}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\textipa{\textprimstress b\textscripta \textlengthmark sk\stackedischwa t}

\Huge
\textipa{\textprimstress b\textscripta \textlengthmark sk\stackedischwa t}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the `tipa` package, this is what I came up with.

`\textschwasci` is a `\tiny` `\textsci` stacked over a `\tiny` `\textschwa` by putting the latter in a `\raisebox` and kerning it back directly over the former.
In `\ctextschwasci` the two symbols are a bit closer together.
As the symbols are quite small, `\ctextschwasci` is a slightly bigger, but somewhat uglier-looking symbol (it "sticks out" quite a bit).

You might want to adjust the kerning before and after the new symbol a bit.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}

\newcommand{\textschwasci}{\kern0.15pt{\tiny\textschwa\kern-2pt\raisebox{2.3pt}{\textsci}}\kern0.6pt}
\newcommand{\ctextschwasci}{\kern0.15pt{\tiny\textschwa\kern-2pt\raisebox{2.2pt}{\textsci}}\kern0.6pt}
\newcommand{\bigtextschwasci}{\kern0.2pt{\scriptsize\textschwa\kern-2.8pt\raisebox{3.1pt}{\textsci}}\kern0.8pt}

\begin{document}
  \textipa{\textprimstress b\textscripta \textlengthmark sk\textsci t \$ \textprimstress b\ae-}

  \textipa{\textprimstress b\textscripta \textlengthmark sk\textschwasci t \$ \textprimstress b\ae-}

  \textipa{\textprimstress b\textscripta \textlengthmark sk\ctextschwasci t \$ \textprimstress b\ae-}

  \textipa{\textprimstress b\textscripta \textlengthmark sk\bigtextschwasci t \$ \textprimstress b\ae-}

  \fbox{\textschwasci}\fbox{\ctextschwasci}\fbox{\bigtextschwasci} \fbox{\textsci}\fbox{\textschwa}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question! After reading your question, I found a useful document (through Google)... There is a package called `TIPA` which has been developed for processing phonetic symbols.[`TIPA` documentation](http://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb17-2/tb51rei.pdf)

Look the sixth page.

Cheers.